# Most efficient way to avoid duplication in data cleansing

Tags: mysql, sql, resources

I've got data coming from a client that is a nice hot mess of duplicated info. I'm going to run a cleaning query which grabs the dumped data, does some cleansing, and ultimately drops it into a new table.

Here's a script for that:

```
INSERT INTO Spend (...)
SELECT ...
FROM Facilities F
JOIN Dump d
    ON d.facname = f.name
    AND f.city = d.city
```

So far so good. The problem occurs when there is a new dump of data. I only want to get the newest stuff. I can't figure out a way to do that that seems efficient. A quick and easy `WHERE NOT` clause won't work (I don't think...) because there isn't any singularly unique column of data. The uniqueness of the entry is really just contingent upon the combination of most, if not all, of the columns. Looping through them all for each dump seems like a terrible idea considering last year's dump for one company is 20k rows. Once we get a few users on here and data tracing back to more than just a year ago it seems like the cleanse would be way too intensive.

Or maybe I'm just a n00b and am making a mountain out of a molehill. Thanks for any advice or pointers-

---

**EDIT #1**

Attaching an image of sample record set
[image]

The first col is an foreign key of the business's ID from the Business table. The rest is purchase records. This table is for searching. The only unique column, then, after cleansing and dumping into the new searchable table is the auto incrementing ID of each row.

Comment: can you give sample records?

Comment: sure thing. see edit above.

Comment: You were describing Columns. There seem to be 10 of them. You characterize the first column and then call the remaining 9 'purchase records'. You're a guy who likes shortcuts, eh?

Comment: not sure what you're getting at, @Tim. if you're trying to be helpful then please expound.

Comment: My point was that batch entry of data without creating duplicates is usually the "hot mess" you call it, and staging new data and cleansing it requires a lot of effort. There are no shortcuts. In order to prevent duplicates, you're going to have to parse out some of the data from the "purchase records" columns so you can create appropriate normalized structures, FK constraints, and performant indexes so that as your data grows, the process of adding new data, and checking for duplicates, won't be too "intensive", as you put it.

Comment: Also, you can have SQL do the checking -- you don't have to "loop through the columns" procedurally.

Comment: I see. I'm new to the data game, thus why I'm posting to begin with. I'm not trying to take shortcuts, just trying to learn best practices, elegant solutions, and the likes. Thanks for the explanation.

Answer (score 1):

The key to eliminating redundancy n a transactional database is Normalization; each additional degree of normalizaiton achieved eliminates another potenial source of redundancy.

In your case, I infer that you have several lengthy text fields which would bloat indices in your primary data table. I suggest that you put each of those in its own lookup table with a (artificial) foreign key lookup from the main data table. This will narrow the key in your primary table, thus reducing index heights and improving performance accordingly. Simultaneously you increase the normalization of the data.

For reporting, subsequently extract the cleansed data into ancilliary de-normalized tables (that is to say, pivot cubes) for more efficient access by end users.

Comment: Thanks for the response. I'll say up front that I only understand about half of it as of right now :) When cleansing the data, I take company metadata and find the appropriate record from another table, grab its unique ID, and then use that instead of all the meta when dumping into the cleansed table. So there's my normalizing of the original data. Might be able to cleanse further, but I'm not certain at this point. Open to suggestions.

Comment: @JohnBlythe:You are going about it correctly; cleaning data always gets your hands dirty.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the interaction and help, guys. I think the easiest solution will be to just have the client only dump in new data. I will append it to an amassing pool of dumped data so I have a continuous record of all the dump and have it also overwrite a `Dump` table before using that to cleanse and send over to my `Spend` table.

Thanks again!